# There's a way to find a single row changed on tfs, visual studio 2019?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

Is there a way to find out who in a project has changed a single row on code?
I.e. if I have got a project that is shared with 2 other people, and we are all working on the same branch and I've found a bug on code, but it's not mine. How can I found out who's changed that part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you are trying to do is a [`git blame`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-blame).  In Visual Studio, if you right click on a line of code and go to Git → Blame (Annotate), it should open a new tab showing who modified/added what line of code last with a commit hash and date.  If you hover over one of these items, it will display a tooltip with additional information, such as that commit's message.

[image: Menu Item]

[image: Blame]

Note that this isn't a Visual Studio specific feature - it's a part of Git.  Most other tools that work with Git have a way to view blames and history as well.

Answer (score 0):

We can add an extension in visual Studio code named"Gitlens"to know who has modified the certain line of code

Comment: There's no alternative for vs 2019? not vs code 2019?